# how to reference global variables in C program from assembly code?

Tags: c, assembly

I have a C program, and I want to access global variables of this program inside an external assembly file. How do I do this? With NASM or FASM assembler.

Sample code here:

```
[niko@dev1 test]$ cat cprogram.c 
#include <stdio.h>

int array[1024];

void func_increment(int position_index);

int main() {

    array[2]=4;
    func_increment(2);
    printf("val=%d\n",array[2]);
}
[niko@dev1 test]$ cat asmcode.S 
use64

global func_increment

section .text

func_increment:
    mov eax, array[position] <- how should I insert here the symbol located inside my C program
    inc eax

    ret

[niko@dev1 test]$
```

I have many number of types in C programs, for example, a struct type which is declared as array and it is about 32MB long:

```
typedef struct buf {
    char                data[REQ_BUF_SIZE];
} buf_t;
```

I have pointers, integers, and a lot of variable types:

```
char data[64] __attribute__ ((aligned (16)));
char nl[16] __attribute__ ((aligned (16)));
uint positions[32];
```

Comment: I have edited to add assembler type, I can use either NASM or FASM

Comment: Yeah `nasm` does require you to declare `extern array`.

Comment: I have read the docs, but the docs specify you have to put the size of the variable, but I don't know how to do this with arrays, should I put the length of array or the pointer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as the symbols go, if they are global you can reference them by name. Depending on assembler and environment you might have to declare the symbol external and/or mangle it by prepending an underscore.

Using 64 bit linux convention and nasm syntax, your code might look like:

```
extern array
global func_increment

func_increment:
    ; as per calling convention, position_index is in rdi
    ; since each item is 4 bytes, you need to scale by 4
    inc dword [array + 4 * rdi]
    ret
```